# Random sample from given bivariate discrete distribution

Tags: r, statistics

Suppose I have a bivariate discrete distribution, i.e. a table of probability values P(X=i,Y=j), for i=1,...n and j=1,...m. How do I generate a random sample (X_k,Y_k), k=1,...N from such distribution? Maybe there is a ready R function like:

```
sample(100,prob=biprob)
```

where biprob is 2 dimensional matrix?

One intuitive way to sample is the following. Suppose we have a data.frame

```
dt=data.frame(X=x,Y=y,P=pij)
```

Where x and y come from

```
expand.grid(x=1:n,y=1:m)
```

and pij are the P(X=i,Y=j).

Then we get our sample (Xs,Ys) of size N, the following way:

```
set.seed(1000) 
Xs <- sample(dt$X,size=N,prob=dt$P)
set.seed(1000)
Ys <- sample(dt$Y,size=N,prob=dt$P)
```

I use set.seed() to simulate the "bivariateness". Intuitively I should get something similar to what I need. I am not sure that this is correct way though. Hence the question :)

Another way is to use Gibbs sampling, marginal distributions are easy to compute.

I tried googling, but nothing really relevant came up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there. Assuming you have the data frame `dt` with the x, y, and pij values, just sample the rows!

```
dt <- expand.grid(X=1:3, Y=1:2)
dt$p <- runif(6)
dt$p <- dt$p / sum(dt$p)  # get fake probabilities
idx <- sample(1:nrow(dt), size=8, replace=TRUE, prob=dt$p)
sampled.x <- dt$X[idx]
sampled.y <- dt$Y[idx]
```

Comment: Reading this again carefully, this is the same solution as what I suggest.  Sampling rows is probably cleaner than combining rmultinom and which.  The key is to realize that rows and columns is just notation.

Comment: Yes the notation is the key. Bivariate discrete distribution is the same as univariate discrete distribution with notation changed. I pick Anika's answer as the correct one, but only because the code is simpler :) Tristan gives better theoretical explanation.

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear to me why you should care that it is bivariate.  The probabilities sum to one and the outcomes are discrete, so you are just sampling from a [categorical distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution).  The only difference is that you are indexing the observations using rows and columns rather than a single position.  This is just notation.

In R, you can therefore easily sample from your distribution by reshaping your data and sampling from a categorical distribution.  Sampling from a categorical can be done using `rmultinom` and using `which` to select the index, or, as Aniko suggests, using `sample` to sample the rows of the reshaped data.  Some bookkeeping can take care of your exact case.

Here's a solution:

```
library(reshape)

# Reshape data to long format.
data <- matrix(data = c(.25,.5,.1,.4), nrow=2, ncol=2)
pmatrix <- melt(data)

# Sample categorical n times.
rcat <- function(n, pmatrix) {
    rows <- which(rmultinom(n,1,pmatrix$value)==1, arr.ind=TRUE)[,'row']
    indices <- pmatrix[rows, c('X1','X2')]
    colnames(indices) <- c('i','j')
    rownames(indices) <- seq(1,nrow(indices))
    return(indices)
}

rcat(3,pmatrix)
```

This returns 3 random draws from your matrix, reporting the `i` and `j` of the rows and columns:

```
  i j
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 2 2
```