# Control frequency over random generation

Tags: r, statistics

I should make a random dataframe that consists of 2 features

```
gender <- sample(c("Male","Female"), 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = c( 0.5, 0.5))
handed <- sample(c("left_Handed","right_Handed"), 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = c( 0.1, 0.9))

data <- data.frame(gender = gender, handed = handed)
table(data$gender, data$handed)
```

and it works fine, but I need to make it in a way that only 1 cell of table has a value between 50 and 90.

I don't know how I can do it?

The current table gives me

```
             left_Handed   right_Handed
  Female          59         4922
  Male            55         4964
```

as you see, it gives me 2 cells with values under 100.

Comment: Why? That seems inconsistent with what seems to be your underlying probabilistic model. If you want to model a dependence between gender and handedness then you would have to first decide what that dependence is and then sample in a way that reflects it.

Comment: You sample independently from the marginal distributions, yet you expect the joint distribution to have a different structure? (There, you have some keywords to research!) See also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281561/random-sample-from-given-bivariate-discrete-distribution

Comment: @JohnColeman it is a requirement of question, to find a solution to control the frequency of each cell

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hit and miss approach:

```
f <- function(){
    gender <- sample( c("Male","Female"), 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c( 0.5, 0.5) )
    handed <- sample( c("left_Handed","right_Handed"), 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c( 0.01, 0.9) )
    data<-data.frame(gender=gender,handed=handed)
    tb <- table(data$gender,data$handed)
    if (min(tb[,1]) < 50 && max(tb[,1])>=50) tb else f()
}
```

This function recursively runs your code until it gets an output it likes.

Typical run:

```
> f()

         left_Handed right_Handed
  Female          59         4970
  Male            48         4923
```

Of course, it would be easy enough to modify the function so that it uses a loop rather than recursion, but the above code is slightly more concise and with the expected values of the cells in the first column being 50, there is never more than a handful of recursive calls required so stack space isn't an issue.